# GCC declarations: typedef __pid_t pid_t?

Tags: unix, gcc, fork

I am confused about the declaration of (for example) pid_t. What does __pid_t mean? Is it another type defined elsewhere? If yes, where? Why is my types.h in ubuntu 13.04 64bit defining pid_t like:

```
#ifndef __pid_t_defined
typedef __pid_t pid_t;
#define __pid_t_defined
#endif
```

and not something like

```
typedef int pid_t;
```

I saw some websites that have types.h headers with the declaration done the last way. This is one:
http://www.sde.cs.titech.ac.jp/~gondow/dwarf2-xml/HTML-rxref/app/gcc-3.3.2/lib/gcc-lib/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.3.2/include/sys/types.h.html

UPDATE:

Ok I found out that a pid_t is an __pid_t which is an __PID_T_TYPE which is which is an __S32_TYPE which is an int. My question now is why is this? POSIX only states that pid_t has to be a signed integer, so why make the declaration enter soo deep in header files?

Answer (score 2):

If you are pulling up your `types.h` via 'man types' then at the top of the header file(under description in the man page) there should exist an include file that defines `'__pid_t'` at some point as a signed integer(if Ubuntu claims that their types are POSIX compliant; otherwise `pid_t` could be anything). The symbol `' __'` is considered reserved(C standard, dunno about C++). If I had to take a wild guess as to why `pid_t` is defined as `__pid_t` and not some int is because `__pid_t` is what Debian's or the Linux Kernel's developers decided to use for the process ID variable name in all of their library functions; therefore only `'__pid_t'` needs to be changed to change the integer size for a process ID.

You should really look around before asking a question, similar stackoverflow questions are easily found: [Size of pid_t, uid_t, gid_t on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922761/size-of-pid-t-uid-t-gid-t-on-linux) .

Comment: And why did the kernel developers decided to do it that way? The link you gave me is off topic

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found what the __pid_t means on the answer to this question:
[Why PID of a process is represented by opaque data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274733/why-pid-of-a-process-is-represented-by-opaque-data-type)

QUOTE

```
typedef __pid_t pid_t;
...
# define __STD_TYPE     typedef
__STD_TYPE __PID_T_TYPE __pid_t;    /* Type of process identifications.  */
...
#define __PID_T_TYPE        __S32_TYPE
...
#define __S32_TYPE      int
```

UNQUOTE

So pid_t is an __pid_t which is an __PID_T_TYPE which is which is an __S32_TYPE which is an int.