# what is the variable type of PID in PROCESS SYSTEM CALL?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, pid

> this is the part of the code for creating child process

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

main()
{
  pid_t pid;
```

> pid_t was declared as the variable of pid.But values are same like integers.

```
  int x = 5;
  pid = fork();
```

> fork() is the function which create child process.

```
  x++;

  if(pid<0)
  {
    printf("process creation error");
    exit(-1);
  }
  else if(pid==0)
  {
    printf("Child Process");
    printf("\nChild Process ID is %d",getpid());
x++;
    printf("\nValue of X is %d",x);  
    printf("\nProcess id of parent is %d",getppid()); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the variable `pid` is `pid_t`. How `pid_t` itself is defined is dependant on the operating system. In Linux it's defined like this:

```
typedef __pid_t pid_t;
```

and `__pid_t` is eventually defined as an `int`. See [GCC declarations: typedef __pid_t pid_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954208/gcc-declarations-typedef-pid-t-pid-t)